# como saber que campo es el que no me guarda

Tags: php, foxpro

buen día quisiera saber la forma de saber cual específicamente el campo que no me guarda Por que me tira error de incompatibilidad

> Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Data type mismatch., SQL state 22005 in SQLExecDirect

Este es mi código:

```
$sql = ( "INSERT INTO btransacciones(sistema_btr,tipotr_btr,codcuen_btr,codcdc_btr,numdoc_btr,fecha_btr,grupol_btr,monto_btr,tasacam_btr,nombre_btr,codprv_btr,motchq_btr,feopba_btr,hechop_btr,revp_btr,autp_btr,comota_btr,nonego_btr,anulad_btr,retend_btr,fechent_btr,lplani_btr,refpla_btr,codpla_btr,codemp_btr,quiengrabo,quienmodifico,horagrabado,horamodificado,fecha1_btr)
VALUES('B','1','$banco','$cliente','$deposito','$fechadoc','004','$monto','1.000000','nada','0000004','002','//','MLE','CB','RC','001','F','F','F','//','F','','','','ADMIN','nadie','$fechactual','','')")
or die(odbc_errormsg());

if(!odbc_exec($con, $sql)){
  echo "no se inserto correctamente";
} else {
  echo "insertado correctamente";
}
```

Muchas gracias por la respuesta Gracias!!!

Comment: Si revisas los tipos de datos de la tabla `btransacciones` y comparas los valores que intentas insertar, sabrás de inmediato cuál es el dato problemático. Si no lo consigues compártenos la estructura de la tabla y una muestra de los datos del insert y te diremos de una vez dónde está el problema.

Comment: Es el campo de fecha  lo teno de tipo date  pero al momento de guardar me tira ese error;             La  fecha la recogo de un input type=date

Comment: Las fechas deben ser guardadas en formato `año-mes-dia`, si no la recibes así tienes que convertirla a ese formato antes de insertar. Muestra un ejemplo de los datos haciendo `echo $sql;` Si colaboras un poco más ya se te habría dado una solución.